# Time out while connecting to the database. Current time out value is 30 seconds

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I am installing a repository creation utility on a windows 8 x64 bit system and getting the following error:

> Time out while connecting to the database. Current time out value is 30 seconds

When I connect via sqdeveloper, it works fine.
My database connection details are:

- Database type: Oracle Database
- Host name: Bonge
- Port: 1521
- service name: XE
- Username: sys
- Password: XXXXX
- Role: Sysdba

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Try to increase the timeout period to JDBC_LOGIN_TIMEOUT=300 in <RCU_ORACLE_HOME>/rcu/config/rcu.properties

Comment: Thanks for your reply but after I changed that parameter , still i get the same error : Time out while connecting to the database. Current time out value is 300 seconds. :( is there any other way to solve this problem.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help guys

I found the solution, the problem was host name when I changed from Bonge to 127.0.0.1 it worked for me

bye

Comment: Sounds like the real issue is either that that DNS taking too long or the host name is incorrect. Does `PING BONGE` return anything? Your 127.0.0.1 ip address will only ever work if it is a local server

Comment: C:\Users\Bonge>PING BONGE

Pinging Bonge [fe80::bc28:4f4b:9b00:cc2%18] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::bc28:4f4b:9b00:cc2%18: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::bc28:4f4b:9b00:cc2%18: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::bc28:4f4b:9b00:cc2%18: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::bc28:4f4b:9b00:cc2%18: time<1ms

Ping statistics for fe80::bc28:4f4b:9b00:cc2%18:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

C:\Users\Bonge>